# Why can I create circle but not ellipses in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code creating a circle:

```
SVGTTest.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", xScale(300))
        .attr("cy", yScale(10))
        .attr("r", xScale(100));
```

When I try to create an ellipse instead of a circle I try the following code, but nothing happens. Any help would be appretiated..

```
SVGTTest.selectAll("ellipse")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", yScale(300))
        .attr("cy", yScale(10))
        .attr("rx", xScale(100))
        .attr("ry", 100);
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code? Your code snippet seems to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found out my mistake was that I used "yScale" on my "cx" and therefore placed it out of the frame on the 2nd snippet with ellipse.